# Extending <object> in Dart

Tags: javascript, html, dart

The Dart `<object>` element does not support a getter to access `<object>.contentDocument` and thus I thought about extending the object to add the functionality.

I took a look at the implementation of the `ObjectElement` and I basically need to add these lines:

```
 @DomName('HTMLObjectElement.contentDocument')
 @DocsEditable()
 Document get contentDocument => _blink.BlinkHTMLObjectElement.instance.contentDocument_Getter_(this);
```

However, I have no idea how to do this. The solution I am using at this time is with a proxy which redirects all calls to the underlying `JsObject` but to be honest, this is not just dirty, it impossible to maintain.

**/* Updated to explain the root of all evil */**

When starting the project I am working on, I wanted to display SVGs, which are uploaded by the user, on the website and let the user manipulate these SVGs by inserting additional SvgElements or removing others.

When downloading the SVGs as a String and displaying them by

`container.append(new SvgElement(svgCode))`

I got really strange display bugs such that embeded images in the SVGs are displaced or even removed and other bugs with masks.

The problem was solved by using an `<object>` tag and set setting its data attribute to the SVG's url. The SVGs are rendered correctly. That being said,  another issue came up. I wasn't able to access and manipulate the SVGs DOM because it's inside an `<object>` tag and the tag's document cannot be accessed by using `contentDocument`.

When taking all this into account, there are pretty much only two options left:

1. I use the `<object>` tag with no display bugs but not being able to manipulate the SVGs or
2. I create new SvgElements fromt the SVG's source and append them to the DOM which let's me manipulate the SVGs but having display bugs.

Since having display bugs isn't really a solution I can only make use of the first option, using an `<object>` tag and working around with Javascript to access the object's contentDocument.

As you can see, accessing the `contentDocument` is not always a security issue and not allowing to make use of it, is just a `quick and dirty` solution of a problem.

When accessing the `contentDocument` by using a JsObject, I get a JsObject back and not an Element. Thus I do not only have to update my code pretty much everywhere, but it gets also pretty ugly since I have to use the JsObject with `callMethod(blabla)`.

Comment: You should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com or at least add your use case to one of the related existing bugs.

Comment: Done. The other thing is that there might be a solution to my problem, (not my question) by fixing the display bugs when apending a SvgElement. Do you have any idea what could cause these display bugs?

Comment: Never encountered it (didn't do anything with SVG yet). You should report that bug as well. Is this in every browser?

Comment: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5e9be0feb98d3aa411bb There you go.

Comment: Update: seems to be a Chrome issue.

Comment: How do you do the SVG manipulation? Maybe there is a workaround possible?

Comment: Since the SvgElement is an Element I query for its children and do standard DOM manipulation such as using the SvgElements' `append(...)` and `remove()`.

Comment: You could load the SVG in Dart and keep a reference and do modifications using this reference and then create a new data-Uri and assign it to `"<object>".data`.

Comment: Nice!! When thinking about it, that may work!! - The only possible problem I see, is that the performance may be not the best one since I always have to convert it to an Uri and the <object> element has to parse it again and again. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know how complex the SVGs are and how many and what kind of modifications you want to do, but because it's all in-memory I wouldn't expect too much problems. If you do this only as a result of a user action (click, keypress,...) I'm sure this will work fine. If you want to animate the SVG this way I guess you should try to find a better approach ;-)

Comment: The SVGs are only changed as a result of a user action, thus, I think I will give it a try. If it works, I owe you a pretty solid cup of coffee ;)

Comment: Ah dang!! It won't work for my use case. I need the user to hover over the SvgElements in oder to select the one he wants to manipulate. Thus I need to add `EventListeners` to the elements and since I do not have a reference to these elements it won't work :'(

Comment: To sad :( I guess the last option is to push the Dart team (explain your problem in comments on the bug reports and the [Dart google groups](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/web)).

Comment: I thought about that too, but let's face the truth. It would take month until the patch is submitted (in case the ticket is not just set to medium priority)

Comment: Sometimes the Dart team is quite responsive (within days), I guess you should at least try. I didn't monitor Chrome bugs closely but here it seems to take much more time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76306/discussion-between-robert-hahn-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class MyObjectElement extends ObjectElement {
  static bool _isRegistered = false;

  static register() {
    if (!_isRegistered) {
      document.registerElement('my-object', MyObjectElement,
          extendsTag: 'object');
      _isRegistered = true;
    }
  }

  factory MyObjectElement() {
    var result = document.createElement('object', 'my-object');
    return result;
  }

  MyObjectElement.created() : super.created();

  js.JsObject get contentDocument {
    // doesn't seem to work with a custom element.
    return new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(this)['contentDocument'];
  }
}
```

use it like

MyObjectElement.register();
  var obj = new MyObjectElement()
    ..data =
    "https://www.suntico.com/wp-content/uploads/DemoStampRotate01-e1400242575670.png";
  document.body.append(obj);

Comment: Yea I know that. But I still cannot access `contentDocument` since ObjectElement doesn't offer a getter to do so. Thus I need to access the underlying Javascript object and perform a call to its `contentDocument` and than convert it to a Dart `Document` in order to use it in Dart. Since the `blink` library is private, I cannot load and use it.

Comment: Maybe `JsObject.fromBrowserObject`. Sorry, I'm too tired to look more closely. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: The problem with accessing `contentDocument` does not only occur when using `<object>` but also with `<iframe>` and `<embed>`. See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19123 or https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12751

Comment: I'm still not sure what you try to accomplish. Access to `contentDocument` was intentionally blocked by the Dart team for security reasons. They have considered to change this since a while but no action taken so far. You can access the `contentDocument` with new `js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(obj)['contentDocument'];` but AFAIK there is no way to create a Dart instance from a JsObject. I updated my answer but `new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(this)['contentDocument'];` doesn't seem to work with a custom element.

Comment: What might work is to embed `<object>` instead of extending it, but you still can't get a Dart `Document` instance from `contentDocument`.

Comment: Much better now, but I can't offer a better answer :(