# How to access contentDocument of object element in Dart 2.0?

Tags: dom, svg, dart

```
<object data="abc.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

I want get the content of the svg,in javascript,it can be get by obj.contentDocument,how to do this in dart?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you'll have to use JsObject.fromBrowserObject:

```
<object id="svgImage" data="abc.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

ObjectElement svgImage = querySelector('#svgImage'); 
var contentDoc = new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(svgImage)['contentDocument'];
```

For details see discussion in other SO thread [Extending <object> in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868564/extending-object-in-dart)